# Custom config in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, config

I develop a little bundle, that provides *tag cloud* functionality. It should be easy, to include it in other Symfony projects and therefore it needs to be configurable. I discovered 3 pages:

- [How to Create Friendly Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html)
- [Defining and Processing Configuration Values](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/components/config/definition.html)
- [How to Load Service Configuration inside a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)

I worked along the examples, but it's obvious, that I miss something, because I get the following error message when I use `php app/console config:dump-reference`:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "loew_tag" (in somePath/blog/app/config/../../src/Loew/TagBundle/Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "loew_tag", found " ... " in somePath/blog/app/config/../../src/Loew/TagBundle/Resources/config/config.yml (which is being imported from "somePath/blog/app/config/config.yml").

and

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "loew_tag" (in /home/somePath/blog/app/config/../../src/Loew/TagBundle/Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "loew_tag", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "blog", "fos_user", "debug", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"

I work inside a 'blog bundle' and try to access the config data for the 'tag bundle'.

Top of my 'app/config/config.yml':

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
- { resource: ../../src/Loew/TagBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
- { resource: ../../src/Loew/TagBundle/Resources/config/config.yml }
```

LoewTagExtension.php:

```
<?php
// Loew/TagBundle/DependencyInjection/LoewTagExtension.php

namespace Loew\TagBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class LoewTagExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        //$container->setParameter('food_entities',     $config['food_entities']);
        $container->setParameter('split_match', $config['split_match']);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new   FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('config.yml');
        $loader->load('services.yml');
        }
    }
```

config.yml:

```
loew_tag:
#    food_entities:
#     - "BlogBundle:Article"
#     - "BlogBundle:Comment"
    split_match: "/[^0-9a-zA-ZöÖüÜäÄß]/"
```

Configuration.php:

```
<?php
// Loew/TagBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php


namespace Loew\TagBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('loew_tag');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('split_match')->end()
//                ->arrayNode('food_entities')
//                ->prototype('scalar')->end()

            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Entries for the node `food_entities` are commented in all files to keep it as simple as possible.

I noticed, that similar questions has been asked and the regarding problems has been solved but I cannot transfer that solutions to this issue.

Any idea, what I do miss?

Comment: Could you link to the other question?

Comment: thx for response, but unfortunately I cannot reproduce the search terms that led me to those questions. I remember, that one posted question has been solved by considering a specific naming convention. It was related to the name of a root node inside config.yml and it's mapping in the treeBuilder inside of Configuration.php and further to the naming of the extension class that has to follow the vendor / bundle schema whereby 'Bundle' is replaced by 'Extension'. It looks like that's not my issue. I will keep on searching for that questions.

Comment: Is the bundle registered in you `app.php`? Also what does the command `php app/console config:dump-reference` output?

Comment: thx for your reply. Assuming, the file you talked about is called `/app/AppKernel.php`: yes the bundle is registered there:
`new Loew\TagBundle\TagBundle(),`
The console command leads to the above mentioned error message

Comment: Is your DI extension loaded? I see a mismatch between your bundle name and the extension LeowTagBundle vs TagBundle.

Comment: Jakub, I take the example, shown in http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html, like this:
A structure like `src\VendorName\BundleName`, `src\Acme\HelloBundle` or `src\Loew\TagBundle` requires the naming of the extension class to be `AcmeHelloExtension` and accordingly `LoewTagExtension`.
Havn't I got it right, and the vendor name must not be part of the extension classname? thx for the hint anyway!

Comment: Yes, but the vendor should also be part of the bundle class name. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name

Comment: This convention in mind, I changed `TagBundle.php` inside the root level of `src\Loew\TagBundle` to `LoewTagBundle.php` and also the classname. In `app\AppKernel.php`: `new Loew\TagBundle\LoewTagBundle(),`

The `FileLoaderLoadException` disappeared but the `InvalidArgumentException` still comes up. Is there something wrong with the DI alias `loew_tag`?  -> `Looked for namespace "loew_tag", found none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by

- keeping naming conventions in mind, especially the part, pointed out by Jakub Zalas
- removing entry: `$loader->load('config.yml');` from the extension file.

Obviously, the config file will be loaded automatically as soon, as the service has been loaded.